# String method of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

I should to write a function, It should accept a string with different symbols and return string of numbers from the passed argument, without regular expression
How can i do this?

Comment: you want to extract all numbers for a given string, is that it?

Comment: and why not use regular expressions?

Comment: What is you input and expected output?

Comment: "... and return string of numbers" what numbers? Are we talking about numbers in the passed string, or charCodes, or what?

Comment: For example 
makeNumber('erer384jjjfd123'); //=>'384123'

makeNumber('123098h76gfdd'); //=>'12309876'

makeNumber('ijifjgdj'); //=> should return empty string ->''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
let str = 'asd6sd4573casxc'


function getNumbers(string) {
    let numbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
       if (!isNaN(string[i])){
           numbers.push(string[i])
       }
    }
    return numbers.join('');
}

console.log(getNumbers(str))
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly
Thanks

Comment: @Thomas it's unnecessary, i misstyped :)

Answer (score 0):

You could extract numbers by looping through the characters in the string and building a list of numbers by detecting if the character code is within the range of `[48, 57]`.

```js
console.json = json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)); // Convenience

const extractNumbers = (str, auto = false) => {
  const result = [];
  let number = '';
  str.split('').forEach(ch => {
    const code = ch.charCodeAt(0);
    if (code >= 48 && code <= 57) {
      number += ch;
    } else {
      if (number) {
        result.push(auto ? parseInt(number, 10) : number);
        number = '';
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
};

console.json(extractNumbers('HE110 W02LD'));          // ["110","02"]
console.json(extractNumbers('HE110 W02LD', true));    // [110,2]
console.json(extractNumbers('HE110 W02LD').join('')); // "11002"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I clearly understand the problem here, but I assume that your input string can look like this:

`Wh3r3 i5 n3m0?`

and you want to extract a kind of substring, which contains only numbers from input string:

`33530`

and because of some reason you don't want to use regular expression... so here is something you can try:

```
function getOnlyNumbersSubstrig(inputString) {
  return inputString.split('')
    .filter(char => char !== ' ')
    .reduce((outputString, currentChar) => {
      if (!isNaN(Number(currentChar))) {
        outputString += currentChar;
      }
      
      return outputString;
    }, '')
}
```